# How would I go about scanning float values in a text file with whitespace characters using I/O Redirection?

Tags: c, io-redirection

I'm pretty new to programming in C and I have a school assignment that requires me to use I/O Redirection and strictly use scanf to read the data from a text file.

I'm mostly checking whether or not the code I've written makes sense and is a plausible method because I can't check whether it works currently (may or may not have dropped my laptop).

Here's what I've written so far.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
    int readingsLen = 5040;
    float readings[readingsLen];
    float* readingsPtr = (float*)readings;

    while (scanf("%.2f", readingsPtr) != EOF){
        readingsPtr++;
    }
}
```

Additionally, here's what the text file looks like. Added the \n to show where the line ends.

```
 22.12  22.43  25.34  21.55 \n
```

Comment: The `scanf()` family of functions largely ignores white space except as a separator between numbers.  You won't be able to tell how many numbers are on a line, nor whether there are trailing blanks on a line.  The cast in `float* readingsPtr = (float*)readings;` is wholly unnecessary.

Comment: You should not test for EOF in the loop condition: you should check that you got one value converted: `while (scanf("%.2f", readingsPtr) == 1) {`.  If there's a letter or stray punctuation character in the file, `scanf()` will return `0` each time you try to read it, leaving the unacceptable character in the input for the next input.  IOW, you will have an infinite loop if there is faulty data in the file if you check for EOF.  Check that you got the correct number of conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 5040

int main(void){
    float readings[LEN];
    for(float *readingsPtr = readings; readingsPtr < readings + LEN; readingsPtr++) {
        switch(scanf("%f", readingsPtr)) {
            case EOF:
               return 0;
            case 0:
               printf("failed to read float\n");
               return 1;
            default:
               break;
         }
        printf("read %.2f\n", *readingsPtr);
    }
}
```

and here is resulting output:

```
read 22.12
read 22.43
read 25.34
read 21.55
```

I find this version, that uses an index instead of a pointer, easier to read:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 5040

int main(void){
    float readings[LEN];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        switch(scanf("%f", readings+i)) {
            case EOF:
               return 0;
            case 0:
               printf("failed to read float\n");
               return 1;               
            default:
               break;
        }
        printf("read %.2f\n", readings[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: *and strictly use scanf to read the data from a text file* — the OP wants the data to be read from a text file and not stdin.

Comment: @RohanBari That is not my understanding of the question, i.e. "use I/O Redirection and strictly use scanf"

Comment: I have also been contemplating this. The condition set cannot be met because `scanf()` cannot be used to read the values from files.

Comment: @RohanBari program < input.txt

Comment: Makes sense. I almost forgot that way. +1

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Me and a fairly experienced friend of mine were looking at it and we ended up making a massive character array that stored every individual character in the text file, which made the rest of the assignment a pain. With this, everything should be smooth sailing. Appreciate you greatly!

Comment: Further, a `switch-scanf` statement would be able to tell the difference between EOF and a matching error, if you cared.

Comment: @Neil I updated the answer as it's more educational.  If you are promised a list of floats but then given different input then the problem changed.

Comment: @Neil Thanks! I actually thought about adding that but I wasn't 100% on it since I won't be able to test anything for a couple days.

Comment: @AllanWind Appreciate the update! Your point on being given different input was essentially what me and my friend were thinking about, which is why we thought about making readings a character array instead and then working from there.